# Dynamic website framework suggestions

Tags: java, open-source, web

What are the open source java based frameworks that can be used to build a dynamic websites?
The dynamic website should allow users to change content in the site. I am not looking for a portal solution, but something lightweight and customizable.

Comment: This will keep you busy during a weekend: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Java_2

Comment: I have already read that. It doesn't tell me which framework offers content management.

Comment: Notice the update to my post, it looks like Play framework has a module for CMS functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.org/). I have worked with it before and it is pretty easy to learn. Extensive tutorials and documentation are on their website.

Because of Play's extensibility, there are many modules for it, one of which is a lightweight [CMS module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/cms). I have not used this module, but it sounds like what you might be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Search about [Spring MVC](http://www.springsource.org/) or [JSF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html).

Comment: Spring MVC or JSF doesn't have inbuilt user controlled change management. They are merely MVC based frameworks. I am looking for something that would let admin users to change content on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Really every Java web framework can be used to create dynamic sites. That's pretty much the entire point of using Java and such frameworks.

If you only needed to serve static content just Apache would be all you need,

There is a bewildering choice of web frameworks in Java. Everyone will tell you theirs is best and all others are bad.

My 2 cents; JSF is one of the most popular choices, rather easy and has lots of support and resources available for it. It's already part of the standard Java EE library, so in most cases you don't have to download or install anything to get started. Any Java EE implementation (JBoss, Glassfish, Resin, Geronimo, etc etc) will do. The only exception is Tomcat.

While there are other choices that also work, it's hard to go wrong with JSF.

Comment: I may have misled by using the term "dynamic websites". What I am looking for is more of a site where content can be changed on the fly without server restarts. Most of the news websites update their content like that. Portal solutions allow that but I feel it is an overkill with other features that it offers. Drupal is one such framework but it uses PHP.